# Identify a Movie In Which a Boy With a Teddy Bear Was a Destruction Machine

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a movie. As I remember, it was like this:

- There was a soldier alone on a far planet who was our main character
- The planet was cold, and iced sometimes
- There was a war that had finished already, but I don't remember its reason
- There were mini-robots like buzzsaws on the ground that were very dangerous
- I remember a lonely boy with a teddy bear who was always asking, "Can I call you daddy?"
- Then the soldier noticed that it was a war machine, and there were many of them.

It was very a good movie. I hope someone can identify it. Thanks.

Comment: I ALWAYS HAD A MEMORY OF MY CHILDHOOD WATCHING THIS SHOW ONLY REMEMBERING THE ENDING SCENE WITH THE TEDDY BEAR EYES LIGHTED UP RED THANKS FOR HELPING ME DISCOVER THE NAME OF THE FILM

Comment: YOUR VERY WELCOME NATE

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've described the movie [*Screamers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screamers_%281995_film%29), which was adapted from the Philip K. Dick short story "Second Variety."

Comment: I just watched it, really great movie, and great story. Thats 90s movies.. Thank you!

Comment: It was sort of nice movie. I think it basically got the flavor of Second Variety which to me was, war had screwed up Earth (movie has it on another planet but Earth I think was devastated also) and now these frigging "screamers" on top of it. There was a sequel to Screamers that I can't even remember really.