# B-class sci-fi movie about postapocalyptic group of soldiers moving from outpost to outpost, with some of them being cyborgs (or diseased?)

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

- The movie was about a group of soldiers (mercenaries?), it was set up in some kind of post-apo setting (deserts, a lot of orange).
- The group was travelling from outpost to outpost, but I don't remember the purpose of this journey (maybe it was to figure out which one was real human?). Alternatively, there could have been only final bunker, but there were a few "pit stops" where they got more "information" to find out whether some of the group members were cyborgs.
- Some of the soldiers were cyborgs / had a kill-switch / had some kind of neurodegenerative disease and over the journey the group had to kill the cyborgs in order to protect themselves.
- There was some kind of internal "am I a cyborg / do I have a kill-switch / sick?" plot - the soldiers didn't know they were affected. I think each of them learned that in each outpost [this part might be very fuzzy!!!]
- I think only a pair of soldiers (male & female) survived.
- At least one (but I think others too!) of the soldiers was heavily armored, you know - black armour with green-light terminal somewhere, heavy machine gun.
- The movie was seen in mid-90s on low-quality TV channel, so most probably made in 70s or 80s.

Does someone recognize what movie could that be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit late for your timeframe, but could this be *[Screamers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screamers_(1995_film))* from 1995? It has the group of soldiers, a desert landscape, and the paranoia of which among them might be a humanoid Screamer as they move between bunkers. And indeed, the last two survivors are a male and a female.

> .... Now paranoid, Hendricksson worries that Jessica could be a screamer as well. He slashes her hand, and is relieved to see blood dripping from the wound. They locate an emergency escape shuttle and begin prepping it for launch, only for Becker (who was repaired and has taken Joe's friend's face) to attack Joe. In the struggle, Joe manages to finally kill Becker by throwing him into a plasma laser that's part of the shield grid for the escape shuttle. With the shuttle now prepped, they discover it can carry only one person. Hendricksson offers the shuttle to Jessica; but a second "Jessica" arrives, confirming that she is a screamer after all, and even more human-like. Hendricksson resigns himself to death; but to his surprise, Jessica shields him, then sacrifices herself in battle with her lookalike. Joe then kills the lookalike with the shuttle's ignition test. With her last breath, Jessica confesses her love for Hendricksson.
>
> Hendricksson departs for Earth on the escape shuttle with a single souvenir, the teddy bear carried by the original "David". As the screen fades to black, the bear slowly begins to move on its own.

### Trailer

Comment: If so, it would technically be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/identify-a-movie-in-which-a-boy-with-a-teddy-bear-was-a-destruction-machine/31861#31861, although I'd be tempted to make the dupe the other direction given how spare the answer is.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the one. I'm afraid mine might be some kind of B or C-class lower-budget schtick :(

Comment: @kolorowa: Did you wind up deciding otherwise?